# Finding Symmetric Difference in an array test fail

Tags: javascript

**sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]) should return [1, 4, 5]**
The expected return is shown above. But I couldn't find why it fails this test. What kind of fix is needed to code below?

```js
function sym(args) {
 //debugger;
 var arr=Array.from(arguments);
  var resArr=[];
 
  arr.forEach(function(arrVal){
        var c=0;

      arrVal.forEach(function(val,index){
      console.log("arrVal",arrVal,"index",index,"val",val,"|",arrVal.slice(index+1-c));
        if(index<arrVal.length-1 && arrVal.slice(index+1-c).indexOf(val)!==-1){
        console.log("here");
         
          arrVal.splice(index-c,1);
          c++;
        }
                    console.log("arrVal",arrVal,"index",index,"|",arrVal);

      });

      resArr.push(arrVal);
    });
  console.log(resArr);
   
  resArr=resArr.reduce(function(acc,curr){
   return acc.concat(curr.filter(function(val){
     var notContains=acc.indexOf(val)==-1;
     if(!notContains)
       acc.splice(acc.indexOf(val),1);
     return notContains;
    }));
  },[]);
    
 
 console.log(resArr);
  return resArr;
}

sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]);
```

Comment: Is it an issue with duplicate elements in the inputs? Seems to work when duplicates are removed.

Comment: @jakeehoffmann yes with duplicates, I can't change input.

Comment: Maybe you could skip over duplicates when iterating over the input arrays then?

Comment: how would you suggest to skip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). [Their support](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Set) should be sufficent. Extend their prototype and benefit from meaningful methods (`union`, `intersection` and `difference` taken from MDN):

```
Set.prototype.union = function(setB) {
    var union = new Set(this);
    for (var elem of setB) {
        union.add(elem);
    }
    return union;
}

Set.prototype.intersection = function(setB) {
    var intersection = new Set();
    for (var elem of setB) {
        if (this.has(elem)) {
            intersection.add(elem);
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}

Set.prototype.difference = function(setB) {
    var difference = new Set(this);
    for (var elem of setB) {
        difference.delete(elem);
    }
    return difference;
}

Set.prototype.symmetricDifference = function(setB) {
    return this.union(setB).difference(this.intersection(setB));
}


var set1 = new Set([1, 1, 2, 5]);
var set2 = new Set([2, 2, 3, 5]);
var set3 = new Set([3, 4, 5, 5]);
var result = set1.symmetricDifference(set2).symmetricDifference(set3);
console.log(result); // as Set
console.log([...result]); // as Array
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more concise version with filtering duplicates.

```js
function sym(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a.filter(function (a, i, aa) {
            return i === aa.indexOf(a);
        })).filter(function (a, i, aa) {
            return aa.indexOf(a) === aa.lastIndexOf(a);
        });
    }, []);
}

console.log(sym([[1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]])); // [1, 4, 5]
```